# “To God Be The Glory”

Tags: verbs

"To God Be The Glory" is a common phrase I see in many places, but when I type it on Word, it suggests it to be "To God *Is* The Glory". Is "be" in the phrase grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I think most native speakers would agree that all grammar checkers are not perfect. (I don't personally use Word.) You phrase also seems to have been appeared since 1872 in a [lyric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_God_Be_the_Glory), so I believe that this is perhaps not a typical usage in modern English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, I think *be* is the preferable word over *is*.

The phrase means, essentially, "May all the glory ***be*** ascribed to God."

One could use *is* and still be grammatically correct – as in, "All the glory ***is*** ascribed to God" – however, humankind seems to have trouble doing that on a consistent basis. That's why we usually say the former (which expresses a hope for a desired state) rather than the latter (which expresses a seldom-observed statement of fact).

Comment: This reminds me of the phrase "God Save the Queen". You answer help me to understand the phrase as *(May) God Save the Queen*.

Comment: And to me this reminds of one of the greatest poems in English, "Pied Beauty" by Gerard Manley Hopkins. `Glory be to God for dappled things..`

Comment: `May there be peace.` We use similar construction in a prayer and such use is often referred to as the **subjunctive mood**.